# Dynamically Add a new Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I have an existing ActorSystem with a hierarchy of Actors. When the Akka system is launched these actors come in to play. However, I have a requirement where during runtime Actors need to be added to the ActorSystem. Is it possible to dynamically add a new Actor definition to an ActorSystem at runtime?

Comment: If rules are generic enough that user can define them why don't you have a single class of actor that can get those rules and act accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Actor is just an instance of a class. If you can create the instance of a class that corresponds to your definition in runtime, then you certainly can add similar Actor to actor system. And in reality it's possible to have generic class that can assume arbitrary behavior in runtime.

So, the answer to your question is **yes**, it's possible to add new Actor definition to the Actor System in runtime.